# Did the early church believe in the supremacy of Rome?

Tags: catholicism, early-church, church-fathers, papacy, rome

Did the early church fathers believe in the supremecy of rome and if so where is the evidance for this? Roman Catholics claim that the church of rome has supreme authority as it is the church of the Pope (ie St. Peter)

Comment: This definitely has Been asked before

Comment: Related : [When did the church in the city of Rome first try to impose a tradition etc](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9479/when-did-the-church-in-the-city-of-rome-first-try-to-impose-a-tradition-on-other/23234#23234).

Comment: Related : [Was Catholicism the first Denomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20550/was-catholicism-the-first-denomination).

Comment: My answer [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/12508/1377) might be the answer to this question — or form the basis of an answer to it.